# Managing incoming form data to ASP classic file

Tags: asp-classic

My website is being attacked.

An ASP classic file is sending data from HTML forms to an Access mdb file also located on the server.

But now someone is sending garbage data and I don't know if it is done through the HTML forms or directly to the ASP file.

Is there a code I can add to the ASP file to differentiate between the two options?

Comment: you might try referral property of server

Comment: Sanitize the data: if you identify it as garbage, ignore and maybe even block future requests sent from that IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It's irrelevant. It's the same if someone sends you the html form with garbage from navigator or if a request is made with curl (or any other tool).

This only determines from where and how the information comes.

It's your asp page who writes them to the database, so, check in your asp sever code that sender has the rights to call your asp, and information sent is acceptable to be saved in db.